I am trying to programmatically resend a pass to an attendee after re-issuing a ticket pass from a PHP function
I was asked to improve the chances of ticket pass fraud from people buying tickets with Event Tickets Plus (The Events Calendar Wordpress plugin). When someone buys say 2 passes to an event they get issued two PDF passes emailed to the the two attendees they added to the event... The purchaser can then go update the Attendee information afterwards e.g. Ticket Holder Name and Email  address.
The worry was that

The new Attendee may not be a woocommerce customer/WP user and
what stops the purchaser from "re-selling" fake passes by continually going to update his two ticket attendees, each getting sent a PDF ticket and when they get to the event the first to check in would get in BUT the rest would not be able to be scanned it via the QRcode scanner and security code attached in the ticket pass...

OK, so I decided to use css to hide the built in Update Attendee Information in the plugin and then using ACF built a form that contains 3 fields

The Current Ticket ID
a new ticket_holder (name) field
a new ticket_email_to (email) field

The form runs a hook called transfer_ticket on update that runs the following function (excuse my bad coding but it works)
    add_action('acf/save_post', 'transfer_ticket'); 

    function transfer_ticket( $post_id ) {

        global $wpdb;
        global $post;
        global $user;
        
        $pid = intval($_GET["tid"]);
        $ticket_holder = get_post_meta($post_id, 'ticket_holder',true);
        $ticket_email_to = get_post_meta($post_id, 'ticket_email_to',true);
        $_unique_id = get_post_meta($post_id, '_unique_id',true);
        
        $_tribe_wooticket_event = get_post_meta($post_id, '_tribe_wooticket_event',true);
        $_tribe_wooticket_order = get_post_meta($post_id, '_tribe_wooticket_order',true);
        $_tribe_wooticket_product = get_post_meta($post_id, '_tribe_wooticket_product',true);
        
        $lastDelimiterPos = strrpos($_unique_id, '-');
        $lastpart = substr($_unique_id, $lastDelimiterPos + 1);
        
        //update_post_meta($post_id, '_tribe_tickets_full_name', $ticket_holder);
        //update_post_meta($post_id, '_tribe_tickets_email', $ticket_email_to);         
    
        // First, make sure the email address is set
        if ( isset( $ticket_email_to ) && ! empty( $ticket_email_to ) ) {

            // Next, sanitize the data
            $email_addr = trim( strip_tags( stripslashes( $ticket_email_to ) ) );
            $exists = email_exists($email_addr);

            
            if ( !$exists) {
                
                $xname = trim($ticket_holder);                  
                $last_name = (strpos($xname, ' ') === false) ? '' : preg_replace('#.*\s([\w-]*)$#', '$1', $xname);
                $first_name = trim( preg_replace('#'.preg_quote($last_name,'#').'#', '', $xname ) );
                $args = array('first_name' => $first_name, 'last_name' => $last_name);  

                $newid ='';
                $length = 6 ;
                $batch = array_merge( range( '0', '9' ), range( 'A', 'Z' ) );

                shuffle( $batch );
                $id = '';
                $keys = array_rand( $batch, $length );
                
                foreach ( $keys as $index ) {
                    
                    $newid .= $batch[ $index ];
                    
                }
                
                $n_unique_id = str_replace($lastpart,$newid , $_unique_id);
                update_post_meta($post_id, 'last_name', $last_name); // for testing
                update_post_meta($post_id, 'first_name', $first_name); // for testing
                update_post_meta($post_id, 'newid', $newid); // for testing 
                update_post_meta($post_id, 'lastpart', $n_unique_id); // for testing                    
                
                
                $username = sanitize_title( $ticket_holder );     
                $user_login = wp_slash( $username );
                $user_email = wp_slash( $email_addr );
                $user_pass  = wp_generate_password( 6, false );;
                $userdata = compact( 'user_login', 'user_email', 'user_pass' );
                
                // Create the new user
                $new_user_id = wp_create_user( $user_login, $user_pass, $user_email );
                            

                // Get current user object
                $user = get_user_by( 'id', $new_user_id );

                // Remove role
                $user->remove_role( 'subscriber' );

                // Add role
                $user->add_role( 'customer' );      
                
                wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user->ID, 'display_name' => sanitize_text_field($xname) ) );    
                update_user_meta($user->ID, 'first_name', $first_name);
                update_user_meta($user->ID, 'last_name', $last_name);
                
                $nsecurity_code = substr( md5( wp_rand() . '_' . $user->ID ), 0, 10 );

                update_post_meta($post_id, '_tribe_wooticket_security_code', $nsecurity_code);
                update_post_meta($post_id, '_unique_id', $n_unique_id);
                update_post_meta($post_id, '_tribe_tickets_email', $user_email);
                update_post_meta($post_id, '_tribe_tickets_full_name', $xname);
                update_post_meta($post_id, '_tribe_tickets_attendee_user_id', $new_user_id);                    
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Ticket has been transferred !!!');</script>";
              
            } else {
                //echo '</br> User exists';
            }
            
            header("Location: https://somewebsite.com/my-dashboard/bookings/");
            die();      
        }
        

    
    }   

In essence and I have tested this the following happens

It creates a new WP user with a customer role 'Customer' if user email does not exists in WP
It updates the existing ticket meta with the new users email and names and the ticket _tribe_tickets_attendee_user_id with the new WP user
It recreates the ticket's security code (used in the QR)
It recreates the ticket's _unique_id that is essential to check in successfully

So the new user can now log in and see his ticket and add it to his Google or iphone Wallet or download his pdf ticket. I have tested with the mobile app and the new issued ticket checks in 100% fine using the QR scanner
NOW THE ISSUE IS
I an trying to get the function above to somehow hook into The Events Calendar Ticket plugin to automatically send the new user his PDF ticket !!! AND i cannot seem to figure it out. I have the ticket ID and the Event ID and the user ID and details, but how do i resend the ticket?
Is there a hook I can call?
I looked through the code in the plugin and only thing that closely resembles a hook or function i can call is situated in wp-content/plugins/event-tickets-plus/src/Tickets_Plus/Commerce/Attendee_Registration/Hooks.php
lines 171-182
`
public function update_attendee_meta_my_tickets_page( $attendee_id, $data_to_save, $data, $order_id, $ticket_id, $post_id, $provider ) {
        $args = [
            'fields' => $data,
        ];

        $ticket = tribe( Commerce\Ticket::class )->get_ticket( $ticket_id );

        // Always inject IAC after Fields.
        $args = $this->container->make( Attendee::class )->inject_individual_collection_args( $args, $ticket );

        $attendee = tec_tc_attendees()->by( 'id', $attendee_id )->set_args( $args )->save();
    }`

Anybody able to help me find a way to resend the ticket as a PDF?
